# Django: Filtering on the related object, removing duplicates from the result

Tags: django, filter, duplicates

Given the following models:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    content = models.CharField()
```

I am looking to pass the following to a template:

```
blogs  = Blog.objects.filter(entry__content__contains = 'foo')
result = [(blog, blog.entry_set.filter(content__contains = 'foo'))
          for blog in blogs]
render_to_response('my.tmpl', {'result': result}
```

However, "Blog.objects.filter(...)" returns the same Blog object multiple times if more than one matching entry is found.

How do you remove the duplicates? Or better yet, am I missing a simpler way to pass the list of matches to the templates?

Comment: I have essentially the same (but more obvious) issue. WHY ARE THERE DUPLICATES IN THE FIRST PLACE? Isn't `filter` supposed to RESTRICT the set? I think it's a bug in django, isn't it? It is kind of like https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12625

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding `.distinct()` will give you only distinct results.

Comment: A subtle point to be noted if you use distinct with a field name ex distinct('field_name'), it wont work on mysql and *only* works for pgsql. src : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct scroll to "Note". Just banged my head on it for an hour, now thinking should have read the doc clearly. :)

Answer (score 10):

See the [QuerySet API Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) for the "distinct()" function:

> Returns a new QuerySet that uses
>   SELECT DISTINCT in its SQL query. This
>   eliminates duplicate rows from the
>   query results.
>
> By default, a QuerySet will not
>   eliminate duplicate rows. In practice,
>   this is rarely a problem, because
>   simple queries such as
>   Blog.objects.all() don't introduce the
>   possibility of duplicate result rows.
>   However, if your query spans multiple
>   tables, it's possible to get duplicate
>   results when a QuerySet is evaluated.
>   That's when you'd use distinct().