# Django: duplicates when filtering on many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've got the following models in my Django app:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField('Keyword')

class Keyword(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I've got the following keywords saved:

```
science-fiction
fiction
history
science
astronomy
```

On my site a user can filter books by keyword, by visiting `/keyword-slug/`. The keyword_slug variable is passed to a function in my views, which filters Books by keyword as follows:

```
def get_books_by_keyword(keyword_slug):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    keywords = keyword_slug.split('-')
    for k in keywords:
        books = books.filter(keywords__name__icontains=k)
```

This works for the most part, however whenever I filter with a keyword that contains a string that appears more than once in the keywords table (e.g. `science-fiction` and `fiction`), then I get the same book appear more than once in the resulting QuerySet.

I know I can add `distinct` to only return unique books, but I'm wondering why I'm getting duplicates to begin with, and really want to understand why this works the way it does. Since I'm only calling `filter()` on successfully filtered QuerySets, how does the duplicate book get added to the results?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979896/django-filtering-on-the-related-object-removing-duplicates-from-the-result

Comment: Please do not use the title to tag questions.

Comment: This is a matter of personal preference and I prefer my questions formatted this way. Just take a look at the related questions to the right, the vast majority begin the exact same way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 2 models in your example are represented with 3 tables: `book`, `keyword` and `book_keyword` relation table to manage M2M field.

When you use `keywords__name` in filter call Django is using SQL JOIN to merge all 3 tables. This allows you to filter objects in 1st table by values from another table.

The SQL will be like this:

```
SELECT `book`.`id`,
       `book`.`name`
FROM `book`
INNER JOIN `book_keyword` ON (`book`.`id` = `book_keyword`.`book_id`)
INNER JOIN `keyword` ON (`book_keyword`.`keyword_id` = `keyword`.`id`)
WHERE (`keyword`.`name` LIKE %fiction%)
```

After JOIN your data looks like

```
| Book Table          | Relation table                     | Keyword table                |
|---------------------|------------------------------------|------------------------------|
| Book ID | Book name | relation_book_id | relation_key_id | Keyword ID | Keyword name    |
|---------|-----------|------------------|-----------------|------------|-----------------|
| 1       | Book 1    | 1                | 1               | 1          | Science-fiction |
| 1       | Book 1    | 1                | 2               | 2          | Fiction         |
| 2       | Book 2    | 2                | 2               | 2          | Fiction         |
```

Then when data is loaded from DB into Python you only receive data from `book` table. As you can see the Book 1 is duplicated there

This is how Many-to-many relation and JOIN works

Comment: Also , by appending `distinct()` after queryset generated from `filter()` , the Django ORM adds syntax [`DISTINCT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_distinct)  for low-level SQL  `SELECT` statement, which  helps to reduce duplicate in result set. For those who are interested, check the value of `str(queryset.distinct().query)`

Answer (score 4):

Direct quote from the Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

> Successive filter() calls further restrict the
>   set of objects, but for multi-valued relations, they apply to any
>   object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that
>   were selected by an earlier filter() call.

In your case, because `keywords` is a multi-valued relation, your chain of `.filter()` calls filters based only on the original model and not on the previous queryset.